# Combination of angular and nativescript

Tags: html, css, nativescript, angular7

Based on the current technology, if I am building a responsive website, is it still advisable to code the Desktop on angular and use NativeScript on Tablet and Mobile versions?

Comment: Yes, you could. You will rewrite your UI (HTML) for mobile / tablet with NativeScript. But you can still reuse / share other parts of the code etc.,

Comment: I see, but would that be an ideal setup in terms of performance? (Loading speed, scalability, SEO) or should I just stick with Angular for both desktop and mobile if I want those?

Comment: In terms of performance, yes. {N} uses native UI components for your app, it should be smooth and faster. But I wonder why you might have to think of SEO for mobile app.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, If you have an Angular project, then you can create a mobile version of the app using NativeScript.

See the link to make the migration:
https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/code-sharing/migrating-a-web-project

You have to make some changes in the views, but you can reuse almost all the logic of the app.